# django crispy forms label override not working

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I can't seem to override the default label with django crispy forms.

model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    house_name_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    town_city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    same_address = models.BooleanField()  
    move_in_date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.label_class = 'sr-only'
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            PrependedText('postcode', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>', placeholder="Postcode", autofocus=""),
            PrependedText('house_name_number', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>', placeholder="Building Number or Name",
                          ),
            PrependedText('street_name', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>', placeholder="Street Name",
                          ),
            PrependedText('town_city', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>', placeholder="Town or City",
                          label="test"),
            PrependedText('county', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>', placeholder="County"),
            Field('same_address', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>',
                  label="Have you lived at the property for 3 years"),
            PrependedText('move_in_date', '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>', required=False,
                          placeholder="What date did you move in to your current address"),
        )
```

Comment: No idea why the crispy form override isn't working. but I did a workaround using `class Meta:` and the label option https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why the crispy form override isn't working. but I did a workaround using `class Meta`: and the label option docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/…

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.helper = FormHelper(self)
    self.helper.label_class = 'sr-only'
    self.helper.form_tag = False
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        PrependedText('house_name_number', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>', placeholder="Building Number or Name",
                      ),
        PrependedText('street_name', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>', placeholder="Street Name",
                      ),
        PrependedText('town_city', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>', placeholder="Town or City",
                      label="test"),
        PrependedText('county', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>', placeholder="County"),
        PrependedText('postcode', '<i class="fa fa-home"></i>', placeholder="Postcode", autofocus=""),
        Field('same_address', ),
        PrependedText('move_in_date', '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>',
                      placeholder="What date did you move in to your current address"),
    )

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['house_name_number',
              'street_name',
              'town_city',
              'county',
              'postcode',
              'same_address',
              'move_in_date',
              ]
    labels = {
        'same_address': 'Have you lived at the property for 3 years?',
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest setting the custom label in the form's `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['town_city'].label = 'Test'
    ...
```

Adding `label="something"` to the Crispy Forms field will result on a "label" attribute on the input field, which isn't what you want.

Comment: This worked form me only when adding this **AFTER** the declaration of the field `self.fields['town_city'] = forms.ChoiceField(required=True)
` in the `__init__` . Thanks